# Is an Android drawable and string resources retrieved as Integers or Strings within a Kotlin map

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, android-drawable, android-resources

I am two days into learning Kotlin in the Android environment.  So building the Google course dice App I  decided to check if I can Localize the App by adding to the `res/` folder another `values/` folder named `values-af_/`.  This is to support one of the local languages.

The thing though is that I want to set the `contentDescription` of an `ImageView` using the `getString(R.string.img_dice_1)` method and set the `setImageResource` to a `R.drawable.image`.  Both of these values will be contained within a dictionary/map/associative array depending on the roll of the dice.
Here is the conditional that check the num variable whether it is a specific number and retrieves the resource:

```
    val drawableRes = when (num) {
            1 -> mapOf("draw" to R.drawable.dice_1, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_1))
            2 -> mapOf("draw" to R.drawable.dice_2, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_2))
            3 -> mapOf("draw" to R.drawable.dice_3, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_3))
            4 -> mapOf("draw" to R.drawable.dice_4, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_4))
            5 -> mapOf("draw" to R.drawable.dice_5, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_5))
            else -> mapOf("draw" to R.drawable.dice_6, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_6))
        }
```

```
        imgOfDice.setImageResource(drawableRes["draw"] as Int)
        imgOfDice.contentDescription = (drawableRes["contDescription"] as Int).toString()
```

When retrieving the values from the map the logcat gives the follwing error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

If I do not cast the map' `contDescription` key to a String I get a `Compiling error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but CharSequence! was expected`

Can someone please point me in the right direction to retrieve the map values?

I found my answer:  I just  had to cast the `drawableRes["contDescription"]` to a `CharSequence` and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

**yes , you are trying to convert "draw" (string) to an integer(R.drawable.x)**

R.xx.xx always return an integer value (say ID)

```
val drawableRes = when (num) {
            1 -> mapOf(num to R.drawable.dice_1, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_1))
            2 -> mapOf(num to R.drawable.dice_2, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_2))
            3 -> mapOf(num to R.drawable.dice_3, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_3))
            4 -> mapOf(num to R.drawable.dice_4, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_4))
            5 -> mapOf(num to R.drawable.dice_5, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_5))
            else -> mapOf(num to R.drawable.dice_6, "contDescription" to getString(R.string.img_dice_6))
        }
        imgOfDice.setImageResource(drawableRes[num] as Int)
        imgOfDice.contentDescription = (drawableRes["contDescription"] as Int).toString()
```

Comment: Hi, Sandrin thanks.  Do you mean I should retrieve the drawable in another way i.e. `R.id.dice_1`?

Comment: ok i will try a solution , but note sure if it works